# ASP.NET MVC: Ajax.Actionlink Does not work with parameters

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-ajax, actionlink

```
        <%= Ajax.ActionLink("DrillDown", "EventOverzichtAjax", new { GroepID = Model.GroepID.ToString(), 
                                                                    groepType = Model.GroepType.ToString(), 
                                                                    manager = Model.isManager }, 
                                                            new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = Model.GroepID.ToString(),
                                                                              OnBegin = string.Format("beginOverzichtFetch('{0}')", Model.GroepID),
                                                                              OnComplete = string.Format("completeOverzichtFetch('{0}')", Model.GroepID)}) %>
```

I'm having some issues with the onBegin and onComplate properties.
They work perfectly as i want. But they do not when i'm trying to pass a parameter with the function.

For example:

```
   OnBegin = "beginOverzichtFetch"
```

Works perfectly. But

```
  OnBegin = "beginOverzichtFetch(1)"
```

Does not work at all. When i use chrome inspector to see where the fault occurs:
[image]

What happens when my link:
Nothing gets updated but i get redirect to the partial view.

Anyone knows how to pass parameters to functions in the onBegin property?

Help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried it but this looks like your problem

http://forums.asp.net/t/1414473.aspx

Comment: The solution:
Ajax.ActionLink("delete", "Delete", "Wall", new { id = wallPost.ID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "wall", OnBegin = "function(){ return onDelete(parameters);

You can also use 'this' as parameter.