# Access the caller DOM-object from the OnBegin function from AjaxAction

Tags: asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Problem: access the DOM-object that called the AjaxAction in the OnBegin function.
Here is one solution: [Question about parameters in OnBegin AjaxOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874163/asp-net-mvc-ajax-actionlink-does-not-work-with-parameters)
Is there a cleaner way to access it?

Examples like these do not work:

```
function beginContactList(args) { // this is the OnBegin
    // Highlight selected group
    $('#leftColumn li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');

    // Animate
    $('#tabs-1').fadeOut('normal');
}
```

Because the `this` object is does not contain information about the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the answer to this question, there they talk about automatically inject additional parameters into the ajax context:
[ASP.NET MVC : AJAX ActionLink- Target an HTML attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488726/asp-net-mvc-ajax-actionlink-target-an-html-attribute)

Comment: That's a workaround. Not something I was looking for. I can write better specific workarounds for my problem. Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no 'real' solution to your problem, but abandon the server side Ajax helpers and do it manually.